# Azure worker roles on premises equivalen or timer job for apps?

Tags: 2013, azure

During the last weeks Microsoft release the AMS package with some videos from Vesa Juvonen and a lot of code samples with some good documentation.

In one of those documents they try to map FTS concepts with Apps concepts.
One of the mappings said is, replace timer services with azure worker roles.

I can understand this easily, we create a cloud service with a worker role, the worker role will make some remote processing to data in sharepoint, lets say that we want to remove old list data to an "archiving" list.

With the worker role on the Run method I can make it run every 30 minutes, and get list data with csom and do something.

I completely understand this scenario, but I cant find a mapping to on premises, I cant create azure worker roles on premises of course, so I wonder if I am in the "on premises" world, my only option is to continue using timer jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An on-premises equivalent to timer jobs is a console application that is run via the OS's scheduler service. (An "at" job for all of us old-timers.

Comment: Or SQL Agent jobs, or Windows services, or WFF workflows that fire based on certain events, etc. There was no mapping because there are so many choices, I suppose.

Comment: with windows service you are still installing something on the farm, so its not really isolated, and windows service runs on 1 server so you would have to do the installation on each server of the farm, which I dont like it. dont like this solution!

Comment: Well, I personally would use Timer Jobs. There are quite a few derived classes that make your life so much easier (Work Items, Site enumeration, etc.). But, you asked about replacements. ;)

Comment: yes me too, but as Microsoft is trying to push "move away from full trust solution" to CAM, then I was trying to figure out if there was a  real replacement for this or not.